# HTML min and max not working for number attribute

Tags: javascript, html

I have an html form that includes, among other things, two number fields that need to take numbers within a certain range.  I'm trying to use the min and max attributes to accomplish this as such

```
<input type="number" id="AutoApprovalDelayInSeconds" min="0" max="2592000" step="1" placeholder="Range: 0 to 2592000"/>
<input type="number" id="AssignmentDurationInSeconds" min="30" max="31536000" step="1" placeholder="Range: 30 to 31536000" required/>
```

but when I enter the form with invalid input it submits with no error display or warning. I know that the number attribute is only a string representation of a number and not an integer or other numeric data type, so do I have to somehow convert this input with javascript, or am I doing something else incorrectly? Thanks!

EDIT. I originally tried opening this in Firefox, which I now know doesn't support this feature.

Comment: What browser and version?

Comment: @MikeChristensen Firefox 22.0

Comment: @macklin https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input Look at the support section. FF is a no go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assuming the form name is `form` this is a barebone script. you should consider changing the input type to text so you won't have to worry about cross browser compatibility

```
<form id="form">
 <input type="text" id="AutoApprovalDelayInSeconds" step="1" placeholder="Range: 0 to 2592000">
 <input type="text" id="AssignmentDurationInSeconds" step="1" placeholder="Range: 30 to 31536000" required>
</form>
```

JS

```
 var delay, duration, form;
     delay = document.getElementById('AutoApprovalDelayInSeconds');
     duration = document.getElementById('AssignmentDurationInSeconds');
     form = document.getElementById('form');


 form.onsubmit = function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   delay = parseFloat(delay.value);
   duration = parseFloat(duration.value);
   if(delay < 0 || delay > 2592000 || isNaN(delay)) {
     delay.focus();
     alert('AutoApprovalDelayInSeconds is invalid');
     return;
   }
   if(duration < 30 || duration > 31536000 || isNaN(duration)) {
     duration.focus();
     alert('AssignmentDurationInSeconds is invalid');
     return;
   }
   // all input appears to be valid so send it
   form.submit(); 
 };
```

Comment: You do not have to change the input type; you can still use `type=number` and thereby have the checks in supporting browsers, even when they have JavaScript disabled, and the element is treated by non-supporting browsers as if it had `type=text`. What matters is that to have some checking in browsers that do not support `type=number`, you need to use JavaScript.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela **YES**. double checking in html and in javascript which is ideal. i did it this way because he didn't make a distinction if it worked on a browser that supports it. But, if javascript is disabled he will be back to square one anyways right? sending invalid form input

Answer (score 3):

Please bear in mind that the HTML5 `input[type='number']` [is not supported by many browsers](http://caniuse.com/input-number), really just Chrome and IE10 (note: **not Firefox**).

Using Chrome I was restricted from posting the form, but on many other browsers you won't be. If you **really** need to restrict user input by number, and want to do some validation, then I suggest you look to JavaScript (perhaps [jQuery Validate](http://jqueryvalidation.org/)).

Comment: Not to worry, we'll actually be able to start using this stuff around 2023 or so..

Comment: No we won't - not when everyone in the business world is still using IE9 (in 10 years time I mean, God I'd love it if that was the case now)